# Web Animations API Custom effects implementation

Tags: javascript, animation, polymer

I've been trying to get to work the new Web Animation API with a "[Custom effects](http://dev.w3.org/fxtf/web-animations/#custom-effects)" animation model. Basically I want to generate call-outs to JavaScript rather than manipulating properties directly. According to the [speck](https://github.com/web-animations/web-animations-js#custom-animation-effects) this should be possible.

Te only demo found at http://web-animations.github.io/web-animations-demos/snowfall/ seems broken, I was unable to make it work with Polymer or native on Chrome 36.

Are custom effects implemented in Polymer or Chrome? Is there a working demo available someware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that is native in Chrome 36 is `Element.animate()` [1](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2014/05/Web-Animations---element-animate-is-now-in-Chrome-36). The rest of the API will come later.

Comment: I do understand that, however the web-animations.js polyfill, not sure if it is still part of Polymer, seems not to work. Shouldn't that work? Thanks for the answer and good job on pushing this to Chrome!

Comment: Thanks! The polyfil should work. If it doesn't please file bugs on the repo: https://github.com/web-animations/web-animations-js/issues/new